# xcode 5.1 keeps modifying my storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode5.1

I've got an odd problem here. Whenever I **view** my storyboard file in Xcode, it immediately gets "dirtied" and needs to be saved. I save it. A second or two later, I see that the icon has gotten dark-gray again, indicating a file change.

The weird thing, is that it only happens on a single storyboard in a specific project. I can open up other projects, and it's fine. The only way to push to git, is to quit Xcode, and then do the commit/push. And the funny thing is, when my colleague opens the project, he gets the same problem on his computer.

If anyone has seen this, I'd love to know your solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion:

This happens for xib files also if the project is being opened in a new version of Xcode. If you check in the storyboard/xib file once in the SVN (git in your case), the problem won't happen anymore. This happens because there are lot of internal version changes that take place when the storyboard or xib file is viewed for the first time. Generally we tend to undo the changes before committing to SVN - as a result every view is a first view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Xcode 5.1. It is not actually modifying the storyboard at all, not updating the version number or anything. Saving and committing the file won't help you.

File a radar.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this issue by locking all of your view controllers in the Identity Inspector under the Document section, selecting Lock > All Properties. Unlock when you need to make changes, then lock again.

More info here:
[The App Canuck - Don't Modify My Nibs](http://theappcanuck.com/dont-modify-my-nibs)